# How to hide collapsible navbar menu when clicking outside of it (Bootstrap 5)?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have a collapsible navbar menu:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapsible">
   .. menu items ..
</div>
```

I want to hide it whenever a user clicks outside of it (so not just when he clicks the menu button again):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    const navbarCollapsible = document.getElementById('navbarCollapsible');    
    $('.container').on("click", function() {
        navbarCollapsible.hide();
    });
});
```

But I get: `Uncaught TypeError: navbarCollapsible.hide is not a function`

**Edit:**

I made it work using the following:

```
$(navbarCollapsible).collapse("hide");
```

But how can I do it without jQuery?

I know I am using jQuery here, but I know that it's not required for Bootstrap 5 - so how am I supposed to use the `hide` method as described in the docs without jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

The error is because `navbarCollapsible` is a element of the DOM and not a jQuery Object. There is no `hide` available.

Try this:

```
$('body').on("click", function() {
  $(navbarCollapsible).hide();
});
```

Comment: thanks, but Bootstrap 5 doesn't use jQuery, so which `hide()` do they refer to? Because if I do it this way with the jQuery `hide()` then I won't be able to re-open the navbar

Comment: The same you refer to with `$` on your other selectors.

Comment: I just found out that I needed to do: `$(navbarCollapsible).collapse("hide");` so the `hide()` is not the method but the variable I need to pass to the `collapse` method. However, how come I use jQuery when Bootstrap 5 does not need jQuery? Or, it's only for the selector, and the `collapse` method is Bootstrap's method?

Comment: Pretty sure JQuery is loaded somewhere, otherwise you could't use the `$` shortcut for `JQuery`.
[JQuery part of this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/javascript/)

Comment: jQuery is loaded because I am using jQuery, but I know that Bootstrap 5 does not require it to work, so I wonder how am I supposed to use the `hide` method as described in the docs without it? (updated the post as well)